# Reading text file word by word separated by comma

Tags: python, list, file-io

I want to make a list of words separated by comma from a text file(not csv file). For example, my text file contains the line as:

```
apple, Jan 2001, shelter, gate, goto, lottery, forest, pastery
```

I want to make a list of each word as:

```
['apple','Jan 2001','shelter','gate','goto','lottery','forest','pastery']
```

All I could do is get the words as it is with the code below:

```
f = open('image.txt',"r")
line = f.readline()
for i in line:
    i.split(',')
    print i,
```

Comment: What about numbers `12,90`. The spaces can be stripped after each iteration. But what's your actual problem? Can't really make that up from what you show.

Comment: I have a file which contains the words separated by comma. I want to make a list of them. for example I want to make the list in this way:
a = ['apple','Jan 2001','shelter'...]
So that I can call each of the value later as:
a[0] for apple
a[1] for Jan 2001

I hope I made you clear this time. Thanks in advance and Happy new year, sir.

Comment: You already have the code right there. Do you understand what it does? You can just `my_list.append(i)` each for loop-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input: `image.txt`

```
apple, Jan 2001, shelter, gate, goto, lottery, forest, pastery
banana, Jul 2012, fig, olive
```

Code:

```
fp  = open('image.txt')
words= [word.strip() for line in fp.readlines() for word in line.split(',') if word.strip()]
print(", ".join(words)) # or `print(words)` if you want to print out `words` as a list
```

Output:

```
apple, Jan 2001, shelter, gate, goto, lottery, forest, pastery, banana, Jul 2012, fig, olive
```

Comment: Helped but I want to make a list of strings not character. for example I want to make a list of words apple,Jan 2001,shelter,gate .. Your code gives what I wanted but character wise instead. Your code gives 'a','p','p','l','e' instead of 'apple'.. Can you suggest how I do this way.?

Comment: What is content of your input file? I added sample input file, and  it's ok.

Comment: But mystery of it, stayed here.

Comment: Sorry for keeping the mistery.. well I mean the code below worked..
`fp = open('image.txt')
line = fp.readline()
words = [word.strip() for word in line.split(',')]
print words`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> text = """apple, Jan 2001, shelter, gate, goto, lottery, forest, pastery"""
>>> 
>>> with open('in.txt','w') as fout:
...   fout.write(text)
... 
>>> with open('in.txt','r') as fin:
...   print fin.readline().split(', ')
... 
['apple', 'Jan 2001', 'shelter', 'gate', 'goto', 'lottery', 'forest', 'pastery']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> f = open('image.txt', 'r')
>>> line = f.readline()
>>> [i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]
['apple', 'Jan 2001', 'shelter', 'gate', 'goto', 'lottery', 'forest', 'pastery']
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Can also be simplified but you will understand it better this way.

```
reading = open("textfiles\example.txt", "r")
allfileinfo = reading.read()
reading.close()

#Convert it to a list
allfileinfo = str(allfileinfo).replace(',', '", "')
#fix first and last symbols
nameforyourlist = '["' + allfileinfo  + '"]'

#The list is now created and named "nameforyourlist" and you can call items as example this way:
print(nameforyourlist[2])
print(nameforyourlist[69])

#or just print all the items as you tried in the code of your question.
for i in nameforyourlist:
  print i + "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir.. Was exactly what I wanted. Happy new year..!!

Comment: Happy new year, I'm glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
f.readline()
```

to

```
f.readlines()
```

f.readline() will read 1 line and return a String object. Iterating over this will cause your variable 'i' to have a character. A character does not have a method called split(). What you want is to iterate over a list of Strings instead ...

Answer (score 0):

```
content = '''apple, Jan 2001, shelter
gategoto, lottery, forest, pastery'''
```

`[line.split(",") for line in content.split("\n")]`