# How to exclude commas while importing a file into a 2D list?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to take information from a file and turn it into a 2D list, my text file has this in it:

```
000001,375.99
000002,212.89
000003,175.12
000002,543.23
000003,1000.01
000001,10.0
000002,23.56
000003,5.65
000009,2.79
000009,1.79
000009,0.79
000008,3.79
000008,10.0
000008,11.1
```

My code can read the file but I get an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '000001,375.99'
```

How do I exclude the commas when the code is reading it?

This is my code:

```
def loadExpensesData():
    exp = open('expense.dat','r')
    data = []
    for line in exp:
        num_strings = line.split()
        num = [float(n) for n in num_strings]
        data.append(numbers)
    exp.close()
    print(data)

loadExpensesData()
```

Comment: If you have comma-separated data, why don't you use [the `csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)? Or, minimal fix, `line.split(',')` to split on commas instead of (non-existent) whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading text file word by word separated by comma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867027/reading-text-file-word-by-word-separated-by-comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:-

change your lines

```
num_strings = line.split()
num = [float(n) for n in num_strings]
```

to:-

```
num = [float(n) for n in line.split(',')]
```

Full code:-

```
def loadExpensesData():
    exp = open('new.txt','r')
    data = []
    for line in exp:
        data.append(map(float, line.split(',')))
    exp.close()
    print(data)

loadExpensesData()
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem!

Comment: @Pottsy please Mark Correct if you find answer Right and helping.